# Sending commands to a Tera Term via script file

Tags: scripting, serial-port, command, teraterm

I am testing some boards and the system used to test these is Tera Term. In Tera Term I use the Serial Port to send commands to the board in order to log in and run certain settings that I want.

Instead of typing these commands each time I test a board I want to create a program that sends these commands without the requirement to type them again and again each time.

Also I need to set a delay between each command as the system needs to to load between them.

**Question**
How can automate the typing of commands and delay between subsequent commands in teraterm?

Answer (score 4):

I used the Tera Term Language (TTL) and created a macro which solved my problem. I used code to wait for a prompt from the system and then print out the command I wanted.

Here's a link to the TTL syntax:
http://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/en/macro/syntax/

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Tera Term for that. It is not made for scripting, but rather for interactive use. Try to get a command line serial terminal emulator.

If you are on Linux you can use `screen` or there like.

If you are on Windows you can just write `echo command > COM1` in a normal `com.exe`-window, according to this link: https://batchloaf.wordpress.com/2013/02/12/simple-trick-for-sending-characters-to-a-serial-port-in-windows/
(Replace COM1 with the name of your serial interface)

Make sure you don't have your Tera Term open while you use the echo-command, otherwise you'll get "Access Denied".

Comment: what about using a .ttl file?

Comment: This is a very uninformed answer.   Teraterm scripting language includes a [very complete API](https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/4/en/macro/command/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what Teraterm is for using the ttl language. It will work great as Adam stated.